# Issue with session.handler.native_file session handler in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, session, nginx

I'm facing a really weird issue with an application i'm working on based on symfony2 (2.5).

Long story short:
in the config.yml file i have this:

```
framework:
  ...
  session:
      name: "a_given_name"

      # THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM
      handler_id: session.handler.native_file

      save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
      cookie_lifetime: 2629744 #1 month
      gc_maxlifetime: 2629744 #1 month
  ...
```

And **session** does not work!
I checked everything, the system create the files but those files are always empty.

Changing the entry realated to "handler_id" in config.yml to: "~" everything works fine.

```
framework:
  ...
  session:
      # CHANGING TO THE FOLLOWING -> IT WORKS
      handler_id: ~
  ...
```

But, as stated in the docs, the "session.handler.native_file" is the default hanlder... so it should work anyway...

Any help about it?
Thanks a lot...

Comment: run `php app/console debug:container session.handler.native_file`

Comment: I've run this command `php app/console container:debug session.handler.native_file` and this is what i received:
`[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
The service definition "session.handler.native_file" does not exist.`
The fact is that the class exists and it's used... I've debugged it...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when running Vagrant machine.

I recommend to move sessions out of the synced folders (default `/var/www/html`) to new location, e.g. `/home/symfony/sessions`

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "/home/symfony/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

Also, helpful article:
https://coderwall.com/p/h3i5mw/symfony-session-problems-with-vagrant

Comment: thanks. I will try it and if it works i will mark this as the correct answer!