# Session variable works on local server, but not on hosting server with symfony2.8

Tags: symfony

I have done an App with symfony 2.8 which works well on local server but not on hosting server; all codes like `$this->get('session')->set('non',$variable);` generate an error and sent me on a 503 error page. some one has an idea?

this is the proper code:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $semester = $request->get('smt');
        $request->getSession()->set('semester', $semester);//generate an error: same with  $this->get('session')->set('semester', $semester)
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('httc_enrollment_registration'));
    }

    $f = $request->get('update');

    if ($f == 1) {
        $request->getSession()->set('update_formb', 1);//generate and error: same with $this->get('session')->set('update_formb', 1);
    } else {
        $this->get('session')->set('update_formb', 0); //generate the same error
    }

  return $this->render('HTTCEnrollmentBundle:Enrollment:index.html.twig');

}
```

Comment: Hello, Seems to be a session_path problem see : https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/session/sessions_directory.html

Comment: thank! i have used `handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/sessions'` as it's in that doc but i still have a same error.

Comment: Is this directory exists and is writable by www-data (Apache user) ?

Comment: yes it exist at app/sessions and it is writable.

Comment: What is your production OS ? Please have a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183818/issue-with-session-handler-native-file-session-handler-in-symfony2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was DoctrineBunle which was for the 5.5+ Php version. so i took another version and it works. thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in config.yml

```
session:
     handler_id:  ~
```

Comment: that was the previous configuration; with which i have gotten the first error